# Gradle: how to display where a dependency conflict arises

Tags: dependencies, gradle, conflict

I have a Gradle project with many dependencies, one of which is resolved as follows:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency javax.activation

:dependencyInsight
javax.activation:activation:1.1 (conflict resolution)
+--- com.sun.mail:mailapi:1.4.4
|    \--- compile
\--- com.sun.mail:smtp:1.4.4
     \--- compile

javax.activation:activation:1.0.2 -> 1.1
\--- compile
```

Version 1.1 must be a transitive dependency because I explicitly specified 1.0.2. How can I find out where this specific transitive dependency comes from?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Answering this question is the whole point of the `dependencyInsight` task. `javax.activation:activation:1.1` is pulled in by `com.sun.mail:mailapi:1.4.4` and `com.sun.mail:smtp:1.4.4`.

If your own code also depends on `javax.activation`, you can force your version with `compile("javax.activation:activation:1.0.2") { force = true }`. If not, you can force a version with `configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force "javax.activation:activation:1.0.2" }`.

Comment: Yep, I didn't realize it. Is there a way to show all the resolved conflicts in one shot?

Comment: You can do `configurations.all { resulutionStrategy.failOnVersionConflict() }`, in which case Gradle will force you to resolve all version conflicts explicitly in the build script.

Comment: You get some information with `gradle dependencies`. If you need more, you can use `gradle dependencyInsight` (for a particular dependency).

Comment: +1. Full examples here: https://www.devsbedevin.net/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/