# app rejected from google play for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy

Tags: java, android

App was rejected for this :
The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep search for:

The output of this command :

```
$ unzip -p YourApplication.apk  | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
```

Is this :

```
GmsCore_OpenSSL
OpenSSLDie
DSA_OpenSSL
DH_OpenSSL
ECDH_OpenSSL
ECDSA_OpenSSL
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers
OpenSSL_add_all_digests
UI_OpenSSL
%s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
OpenSSL CMAC method
OpenSSL default
OpenSSL DH Method
OpenSSL PKCS#3 DH method
OpenSSL DSA method
OpenSSL EC algorithm
OpenSSL ECDH method
OpenSSL ECDSA method
OpenSSL HMAC method
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html
OpenSSL RSA method
OpenSSL default user interface
}AES part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
ASN.1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
Blowfish part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
Big Number part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
OCAMELLIA part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
\CAST part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
CONF part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
CONF_def part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
DES part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
libdes part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
Diffie-Hellman part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
DSA part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
EC part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
(1ECDH part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
ECDSA part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
EVP part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
IDEA part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
lhash part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
MD4 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
MD5 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
PEM part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
RAND part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
RC2 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
RC4 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
RIPE-MD160 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
RSA part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
SHA part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
SHA1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
SHA-256 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
DlSHA-512 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
Stack part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
TXT_DB part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
X.509 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support
could not parse PKCS12 file, check password, OpenSSL error %s
OpenSSL/%lx.%lx.%lx%s
OpenSSLDie
OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
SSLv2 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
SSLv3 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
TLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
DTLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
```

The problem i am not using openssl on my app. Maybe there is a third library i don't know which one .

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.lawloretienne:imagegallery:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2')

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'

    compile 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.5'

    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
```

Please i need help.

Comment: Try to list all of the dependencies of your dependencies, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311727/gradle-how-to-display-where-a-dependency-conflict-arises) may help. And then see which 3rd party lib is using SSL.

Comment: I bet it's `crashlytics`. Had a similar issue with them regarding `Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID`. Updating the version to `2.9.5` solved it.

Comment: @HedeH Could not find io.sentry:sentry-android:2.9.5

Comment: @Vucko i will try this and come back to you

Comment: I wrote `crashlytics`  -  `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar`. Not `sentry`.

Comment: thank you every one i find out the reason it was due to an old library. (Vibex) but files are still in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the error it was due to https://github.com/bia-nca/Vibex ( library not used any more in the project but so files associated to it are making troubles.