# gradle 4.10 + java11 = dependency version detection problem with spring(and many other libraries)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, java-11

I'm working under project conversion from java 8 to 11 + gradle 4.5 -> 4.10.3 and found very strange thing for me. gradle take wrong jar versions . for example part of

> gradle dependencies

```
\--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.1.3.RELEASE -> 4.2.2.RELEASE
    Line 407: |              +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.4.RELEASE (*)
    Line 408: |              +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.4.RELEASE (*)
    Line 409: |              +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.4.RELEASE (*)
    Line 410: |              +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.4.RELEASE (*)
    Line 411: |              \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.4.RELEASE (*)
    Line 419: |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8 -> 2.8.7 (*)
    Line 420: |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.8 -> 2.8.7
    Line 423: |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.8 -> 2.8.7
    Line 427: |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.9.8 -> 2.8.7
    Line 432: |    |    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.14 -> 8.5.11
    Line 433: |    |    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.14 -> 8.5.11
    Line 434: |    |    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.14 -> 8.5.11
    Line 437: |    |    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final -> 1.1.0.Final
    Line 438: |    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final -> 3.3.0.Final
```

spring-security-web:5.1.3.RELEASE -> 4.2.2.RELEASE !!!
tomcat-embed-core:9.0.14 -> 8.5.11!!! 
tomcat-embed-el:9.0.14 -> 8.5.11!!!
org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.14 -> 8.5.11!!!
and application failed in runtime:

```
An attempt was made to call the method org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.setAcceptCount(I)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol, is available from the following locations:

 jar:file:/C:/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy/bin/java/TxVersionServer/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProtocol.class

 It was loaded from the following location:

 file:/C:/Program%20Files/Dalet/DaletPlus/bin/java/TxVersionServer/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar
```

it mean gradle use version X for compilation and version Y for runtime, why compilation was not failed ? method exists only in version 9. compilation must fail on it, no? how I can avoid it? looks like I need specify version of 3d party dependencies in my gradle too, for example: A depends on B , B depends on C, and I need to write in A: A depends on B and A depends on C. I tested it and this work, but it's look very and very wrong way. any ideas how to resolve dependencies without such version hops.

Answer (score 1):

This Gradle version does not seem to support Java 11. See Issue [7835](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7835)

You will have to upgrade to Gradle 5.0 to use Java 11, see [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/release-notes.html).

There are some mentions that [Gradle itself will run with Java 11](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/release-notes.html) but not for builds themselves. It looks a bit confusing but the release notes a quite clear that Java 11 support comes only with Gradle 5.0+

Comment: same gradle dependencies output after gradle update to gradle 5. looks like dependency resolver totally broken  :(

Comment: there is usually a reason for this different resolutions gradle does. Did you go through the upgrade guide? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html
and does the dependencyInsight task not tell where those versions come from? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311727/gradle-how-to-display-where-a-dependency-conflict-arises