# Disable org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a very simple spring boot project to consume from a kafak topic , but when i run i keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:423)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:402)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:393)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:236)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.stellapps.test.ota.Test.main(Test.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:188)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:419)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

why is it even trying to dectect kotlin related file or classes when everything i have is in java , i want to disable this, how can i disable this??

Comment: you should check your spring for a conflicted/outdated version, this class is in spring-core (!) since 5.0

Comment: [maven?](https://dzone.com/articles/solving-dependency-conflicts-in-maven) gradle? (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21311727/592355)

Comment: @xerx593 how can i check for conflicted/outdated version?

Comment: its maven by the way

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-core`

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html ;)